# USB Device to Android Communication

Tags: java, android

I am researching and trying to find more information how to get a USB Device to send commands to my phone. For example, I will have a device attached to my SAMSUNG GALAXY NOTE 3 - through the charging port. I will have some sort of device that we can call a "controller". This controller will have buttons on it. I want to know if anyone can point me in the right direction for what exactly it is that I need. Basically I need these buttons to be able to perform commands on my phone, for example - Open An App. Take A Picture, etc.

I see a lot of threads about how one would use their phone to send data TO a device, but I need a device to send data to my phone.

Is this possible? If so, can you maybe point me in the right direction towards useful resources? Thanks!

Comment: The direction of data flow doesn't really make more than a small difference.  It's always controlled by the host, but usually flows in both directions.  I believe somewhere there is an official sample for a usb game controller, the issue would then be if your program can accomplish all of your goals by issuing Intents, or if some are too privileged for that.

Comment: You need to read about HID apis on the android developer site. The example from google its called Missle Launcher. You will find it if you google by that name.

Comment: this video presentation its also very usefull http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=s7szcpXf2rE